# NSFetchedResultsController not showing new object with nil section name from child object

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have Items that each has-one Category. I use a `NSFetchedResultsController` to show the items and group them into sections by category name.

```
self.fetchedResultsController = [Item MR_fetchAllSortedBy:@"category.categoryName" ascending:YES withPredicate:nil groupBy:@"category.categoryName" delegate:self];
```

But when I add two new items as below, only the one with a category gets inserted into the list. If I restart the app, the one without a Category name is shown at the top without section just as it should.

*This is how I do the insertion (using Magical Record):*

```
Category *category = [Category MR_createEntity];
category.categoryName = @"My Category";

Item *itemWithCategory = [Item MR_createEntity];
itemWithCategory.itemName = @"Item with category";
itemWithCategory.category = category;

Item *itemWithoutCategory = [Item MR_createEntity];
itemWithoutCategory.itemName = @"Item without category";

[[NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread] MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
```

**Why does the `NSFetchedResultsController` not get notified when a new item is added when the `sectionNameKeyPath` is referencing an attribute on a child object and this child object is nil?**

Comment: This happens not just when the section name key path references a related object, but also when the key is on the fetched object itself. For example, if you section them on Item.name and then add one with and one without a name, you'll see the same effect. In this case, though, you can just always use "" instead of nil to circumvent the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had extremely bad luck trying to sectionate fetchedResultsController results with a nil section value. The docs don't mention, but I don't think it's actually allowed.

It's also not clear from the docs, but: the property you use for sectionation need not actually be a modeled property, and can be synthetic. (This can be extremely handy when, for example, using dates as sections.)

So, my usual workaround is to create a synthetic readonly property, `Item.formattedCategoryTitle` say, that returns `Item.category.categoryName` if not nil and an appropriate placeholder otherwise. Perhaps a tiny bit slower - I think Core Data takes advantage if the section property *is* in the database - but it works.

---

(P.S. another small gotcha: The documentation claims that "Any change in the context that affects the result set or section information is processed and the results are updated accordingly." This is not strictly true: only changes to the fetched entity are noticed.

In this case, if `Category` objects themselves change (a new title is assigned, for example), the fetchedResultsController will not notice. It only notices changes to, in this case, the `Item` objects - they themselves must change for the controller to reevaluate their presence, order, sectionation, etc.

If this is likely to happen, you can either: set up a second fetchedResultsController just to watch the categories for change, and trigger a refetch of the main controller; or register for  `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification` and detect category changes there; or write `Category` so that it "dirties" its items if it changes, by, e.g., making a null change on them. I've tried these methods and am open to hearing better ones!)

Comment: (I say "synthetic" rather than "transient" because the formattedCategoryTitle has no storage at all; it's computed on request, and need not be modeled at all. A "transient" property actually has a backing ivar that just isn't persisted back to the db, and may or may not be in the model.)